# Flutter Timezone (as ZoneId)

Tags: timezone, flutter

I am relative new to Flutter. While I was experimenting, I came across with an issue. My REST Api takes a timezone parameter (Zone ID format such as Europe/London).

I saw both https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_native_timezone and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/timezone, but neither of those serve my needs.

My goal is, when the user connect to the internet (without giving any location access to the app, if it is possible), get the timezone in ZoneId format and feed my back end in order to make the necessary date and time adjustments. Something similar to this

```
>>> var timezone = jstz.determine();
>>> timezone.name(); 
"Europe/London"
```

Presented in https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Any insights will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where will you get the timezone without location access ?

Comment: For example when I building a site a use timezone.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-js) at the front end and this gives me all I need. I do not know if same things apply on a mobile application. I am relative new to this area. My desired behavior is, when the user launches the app, the app should know where the user came from (just like at some websites). Probably, I am missing something. Any insights will be really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

I've been also looking for this and here's what I found: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone

It a bit hacky under the hood, but it seems to work properly on both iOS and Android. Hope this will help someone in need.

Usage:

```dart
final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
print(currentTimeZone); // Europe/Moscow
```

Comment: I'm considering this package, but also concerned by your comment "a bit hacky under the hood"... could you please explain your thoughts further?

Comment: Just for the record, it seems to fail on windows. MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLocalTimezone on channel flutter_native_timezone))

Comment: This plugin seems to no longer be maintained and isn't compatible with the latest versions of Flutter/Gradle

Answer (score 2):

Came up with a simple solution:

```
//server time(UTC)
String date_to_parse = "2019-06-23 12:59:43.444896+00:00";
DateTime server_datetime = DateTime.parse(date_to_parse);

//get current system local time
DateTime local_datetime = DateTime.now();

//get time diff
var timezoneOffset = local_datetime.timeZoneOffset;
var time_diff = new Duration(hours: timezoneOffset.inHours, minutes: timezoneOffset.inMinutes % 60);

//adjust the time diff
var new_local_time = server_datetime.add(time_diff);
```

Comment: Just a head's up, but I tested this out and noticed that it's not going to work for timezones with minute-based offsets (e.g., "Newfoundland Daylight Time" is GMT-2:30)


But if you replace your line starting with "var time_diff" with this, it seems to work fine: 


```var timeDiff = new Duration(minutes: timezoneOffset.inMinutes);```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after the Time Zone offset. All you need is one line of code

int tzOffset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inHours;

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I found a (temporary) workaround to my issue.

Using

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var timezoneOffset = now.timeZoneOffset;
```

I got the timezoneOffset in UTC format in flutter. Then send it to my back end as string (i.e. "-04") and drift my ZoneId properly.

```
Integer tzOffsetHour = Integer.valueOf(covertToTimezone);
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(tzOffsetHour, 0);
ZoneId zoneTZ = ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", offset);
LocalDateTime localDateTimeClient = new Date().toInstant().atZone(zoneTZ).toLocalDateTime();
```

As a result I take the local time and date as stated in user's device, without using any location services, which was my goal from the beginning.

Until now, I have not faced any issues... we will see...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `.toLocal()` to your DateTime object.

```
myDate = otherDate.toLocal();

myDate = DateTime.parse(json['server_date']).toLocal();
```

Comment: It doesn't add any info though. Just a solid timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `timezone`. as below

```dart
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

String getNameLocalTimeZone() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  var locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;

  int milliseconds=DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inMilliseconds;
  String name = "";

  locations.forEach((key, value) {
    for (var element in value.zones) {
      if (element.offset == milliseconds) {
        name = value.name;
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  return name;
}
```

Comment: Timezone definitions are subject to, and do, change. You're essentially leveraging hardcoded definitions in your solution.

Comment: @drrkmcfrrk This is the best way to support dart and flutter

Comment: What happens when timezone defs change? Do you up-version your app and roll it out to users so that you can do the above accurately and reliably?

Comment: @drrkmcfrrk The timezone library will be updated after the change. If you want more accuracy, I think you should use the timezone online api

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset   // +5:30:00.000000 is expected format
```

Comment: Doesn't return offset with + as a prefix. The actual output is `1:00:00.000000` ( UK timezone)