# How to get current timezone region (tz database name) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, timezone

I am new to flutter and my rest api takes current timezone as Europe/london. I don't know to get current timezone in flutter. There is a question in stackoverflow about this topic but no user gave the answer.

[Flutter Timezone (as ZoneId)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361843/flutter-timezone-as-zoneid)

Can anyone guide me, how can i get the current timezone in flutter using dart.

Comment: For name you can use - `DateTime.now().timeZoneName `

Comment: I don't want this format, my api takes Europe/london timezone's format. but this code give me The Europe Standard time

Comment: DO NOT USE `DateTime.now().timeZoneName`! Timezone abbreviations are ambiguous. CST for example can mean Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time. There's a wiki page that explains more (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). It's not ISO 8601 compliant, and mostly deprecated for modern use. Confused as to why the Dart team makes these timezones more accessible than the tz timezone regions.

Comment: @MehulRanpara - While probably not an ideal solution, if you use the Windows operating system, `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` should return the full time zone name (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneName.html).

Answer (score 35):

`DateTime` is the default class give use timezone and time offset both required to solve timezone related issue.

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
 print(dateTime.timeZoneName);
 print(dateTime.timeZoneOffset);
```

**Output:**

**1. India**

```
timeZoneName: IST
timeZoneOffset: 5:30:00.000000
```

**2. America/Los_Angeles**

```
timeZoneName: PST
timeZoneOffset: -8:00:00.000000
```

timezone list: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/timezone

Comment: dateTime.timeZoneName returns only "+5:30"  not IST

Comment: Just Checked: It returns Abbreviated String. `DateTime.now().timeZoneName`

Comment: dateTime timeZoneName returns +0430 for me, I can't get the abbreviation

Comment: @DNS go to darpad.dev and try this code 
```void main() {
  print(DateTime.now().timeZoneName);
}```

Comment: OP wants a solution that gives the tz timezone region, so `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` and `DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset` are not solutions.

Comment: The `timeZoneName` (which gives an abbreviation on all systems except Windows) and `timeZoneOffset` when combined might be enough to answer the OPs question. But one would need to build a map, that uses the `timeZoneName` and `timeZoneOffset` to pick the correct tz timezone region.

Comment: "Mitteleuropäische Zeit" is the timeZoneName in germany. And that is completely useless if not insanely ridiculous!

Answer (score 18):

There is a great library for this:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone

Comment: I'm using flutter_timezone instead of flutter_native_timezone because the author of flutter_native_timezone seems to have stopped developing. Source: https://github.com/pinkfish/flutter_native_timezone/issues/56#issuecomment-1592359347

Answer (score 14):

> /// The time zone name.   ///   /// This value is provided by the
> operating system and may be an   /// abbreviation or a full name.
> ///   /// In the browser or on Unix-like systems commonly returns
> abbreviations,   /// such as "CET" or "CEST". On Windows returns the
> full name, for example   /// "Pacific Standard Time".
> `external String get timeZoneName;`
>
> /// The time zone offset, which   /// is the difference between
> local time and UTC.   ///   /// The offset is positive for time zones
> east of UTC.   ///   /// Note, that JavaScript, Python and C return
> the difference between UTC and   /// local time. Java, C# and Ruby
> return the difference between local time and   /// UTC.
> `external Duration get timeZoneOffset;`

`DateTime.now().timeZoneName`

If time instance is in UTC.

`timeInstance.toLocal().timeZoneName`

Moreover,

> /// The DateTime class does not provide internationalization. /// To
> internationalize your code, use /// the
> [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

OR

To get timezone in `Europe/Moscow` format:
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278162/4669744): Using [flutter_native_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone)

```
final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
print(currentTimeZone); // Europe/Moscow
```

Comment: this package is good but not working on windows

Answer (score 4):

```
// Use this

Map timezoneNames = {
  0: 'UTC',
  10800000: 'Indian/Mayotte',
  3600000: 'Europe/London',
  7200000: 'Europe/Zurich',
  -32400000: 'Pacific/Gambier',
  -28800000: 'US/Alaska',
  -14400000: 'US/Eastern',
  -10800000: 'Canada/Atlantic',
  -18000000: 'US/Central',
  -21600000: 'US/Mountain',
  -25200000: 'US/Pacific',
  -7200000: 'Atlantic/South_Georgia',
  -9000000: 'Canada/Newfoundland',
  39600000: 'Pacific/Pohnpei',
  25200000: 'Indian/Christmas',
  36000000: 'Pacific/Saipan',
  18000000: 'Indian/Maldives',
  46800000: 'Pacific/Tongatapu',
  21600000: 'Indian/Chagos',
  43200000: 'Pacific/Wallis',
  14400000: 'Indian/Reunion',
  28800000: 'Australia/Perth',
  32400000: 'Pacific/Palau',
  19800000: 'Asia/Kolkata',
  16200000: 'Asia/Kabul',
  20700000: 'Asia/Kathmandu',
  23400000: 'Indian/Cocos',
  12600000: 'Asia/Tehran',
  -3600000: 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde',
  37800000: 'Australia/Broken_Hill',
  34200000: 'Australia/Darwin',
  31500000: 'Australia/Eucla',
  49500000: 'Pacific/Chatham',
  -36000000: 'US/Hawaii',
  50400000: 'Pacific/Kiritimati',
  -34200000: 'Pacific/Marquesas',
  -39600000: 'Pacific/Pago_Pago'
};

data[DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inMilliseconds] // Ex : Indian/Mayotte
```

Comment: Please update the formatting so it is easier to use. Consider using code blocks. Makes it easier for people that stumble across this answer to it more easily.

Comment: how is this approach working regarding swaps of summer/winter times in those countries where it is present?

Answer (score 2):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/timezone with https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneOffset.html might work for you.

You can always make native functionality available to Flutter by building an https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12531 is also somewhat related.

Comment: i do not understand and little bit confuse about how to get the timezone. 
Can You plz give me the snippet of getting current timezone ? @Gunter Zochbauer

Comment: The package docs should explain it. I don't have a concrete snippet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The docs of `timezone` don't explain it. In fact `timezone` is incapable of getting the current timezone as it will use `UTC` as local timezone until you set it yourself, [which apparently is a problem in itself](https://github.com/srawlins/timezone/issues/50) and its solution leads to @AlexanderKrol's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dart does not provide a tz timezone for the platform directly, however one can use the following two properties and a mapping to determine the tz timezone.

---

(1) The `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` property gives a timezone abbreviation (on Windows it gives a full name). This abbreviation alone is not enough to determine a time zone. For example, CST can mean Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, China Standard Time, etc.

(2) The `DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset` property gives a UTC offset, which vertical spans multiple timezones. This alone is not enough to determine a timezone.

---

To determine the tz timezone, use both the `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` and `DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset` properties, and map to the appropriate tz timezone.

Example below (which could be created as a Flutter package):

```dart
String timeZone = DateTime.now().timeZoneName.toString();
String timeZoneOffset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.toString();

String tzTimeZoneName = '';
String timeZoneName = '';

if (
  (timeZone == 'CST' || timeZone == 'CST ( Central Standard Time )') &&
  timeZoneOffset == '-6:00:00.00-0.0'
) {
  tzTimeZoneName = 'America/Chicago';
  timeZoneName = 'Central Standard Time';
}
```

These two pages can be used to create a full mapping:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

> **Note:** This mapping technique can also be used to convert the timezone abbreviation into the full name timezone (on non-Window systems). For example CST, to "Central Standard Time". I also think the Dart team, could have patched this on non-Window systems, as they have both the timezone abbreviation and the UTC offset. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

add this in your pub

```
flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
```

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

```
 void getTimeZone() async{
    const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('flutter_native_timezone');
    final String? localTimezone = await channel.invokeMethod("getLocalTimezone");
    print(localTimezone);
  }
```

output -> Asia/Karachi

Answer (score 0):

I throw off my implementation example when you need to check and limit the list of time zones. Perhaps this will help someone.

Use [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

enum TimeZone {
  kaliningrad('Europe'),
  moscow('Europe'),
  samara('Europe'),
  yekaterinburg('Asia'),
  omsk('Asia'),
  krasnoyarsk('Asia'),
  novosibirsk('Asia'),
  irkutsk('Asia'),
  chita('Asia'),
  vladivostok('Asia'),
  magadan('Asia'),
  sakhalin('Asia'),
  srednekolymsk('Asia'),
  anadyr('Asia'),
  kamchatka('Asia');

  const TimeZone(this.continent);

  final String continent;

  String get id {
    final name = '${this.name[0].toUpperCase()}'
        '${this.name.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
    return [continent, name].join('/');
  }
}

TimeZone? get timeZone {
  try {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
    final offset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inMilliseconds;
    final zones = locations.keys.where(
      (zone) => locations[zone]?.currentTimeZone.offset == offset,
    );
    return TimeZone.values.firstWhereOrNull(
      (tz) => zones.any((z) => z == tz.id),
    );
  } catch (e, s) {
    return null;
  }
}

void main() {
  final current = timeZone ?? TimeZone.moscow;
  print(current.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using [flutter_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_timezone).

```
 static Future<String> getCurrentTimezone() async {
    final String currentTimeZone = await 
    FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    return currentTimeZone;
  }
```

Output:

```
Europe/london
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  var date = DateTime.now().toIso8601String().split(".")[0];
  if(DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.isNegative){
    date += "-";
  } else {
    date += "+";
  }
  final timeZoneSplit = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.toString().split(":");

  var hour = int.parse(timeZoneSplit[0]);
  if(hour < 10){
    date += "0${timeZoneSplit[0]}";
  }
  date += ":" + timeZoneSplit[1];
  print(date);
```

This will work and this will give something like `2021-07-15T19:28:25+05:30`. Here 5:30 is IST. Which should be good.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().toLocal();
var date = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(startDate);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Maybe useful for someone, I'm using:

```
String formatDateToStringWithTimeZone(DateTime date) {
  var dur = date.timeZoneOffset;
  if (dur.isNegative)
    return "${DateFormat("y-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").format(date)}-${dur.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(dur.inMinutes - (dur.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
  else
    return "${DateFormat("y-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").format(date)}+${dur.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(dur.inMinutes - (dur.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
}
```

Comment: What if the offset 1:30, wouldn't be a bug in the above code then?