# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method log on channel testfairy)

Tags: flutter, dart, testfairy

I'm trying to build an Android app, but receive an error MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method log on channel testfairy):

```
E/flutter ( 8121): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)
E/flutter ( 8121): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
E/flutter ( 8121): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8121): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter ( 8121): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:67:27)
E/flutter ( 8121): #3      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:97:13)
E/flutter ( 8121): #4      NotificationHelper.initNotifications (package:boxview_mobile_flutter/services/notification_helper.dart:23:37)
E/flutter ( 8121): #5      new Routes (package:boxview_mobile_flutter/routes.dart:49:26)
E/flutter ( 8121): #6      main (package:boxview_mobile_flutter/main.dart:4:7)
E/flutter ( 8121): #7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:25)
E/flutter ( 8121): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 8121): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 8121): #10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
E/flutter ( 8121): #11     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
E/flutter ( 8121): #12     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:5)
E/flutter ( 8121): #13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
E/flutter ( 8121): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Current version of TestFairy plugin: testfairy: ^2.0.1
Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2)
Dart version 2.10.2.
Also, I've added `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

I run the app with the command `flutter run --enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety`.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method show on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local\_notifications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471697/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-show-on-channel-dexter)

Comment: Hi, can you check if this happens when you disable Firebase and rebuild?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but unfortunately, that link above and disabling the firebase_messaging plugin didn't help me.

Comment: Can you contact to support@testfairy.com to further debug this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278077/13078639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Akif has pointed in the right direction of a reason for the problem. In fact, this was due to the local_notifications plugin. I managed to solve this problem by switching the flutter to the beta channel (Flutter 1.23.0-18.1.pre • channel beta).