# Flutter: How to set the local timezone to be device timezone?

Tags: flutter

When I run the app on the real device to test the `flutter_local_notifications`, the timezone name shows Hong Kong. The problem is the TZDateTime is using UTC+0, but the Hong Kong timezone should be UTC+08:00. Is something going wrong?

initial the timezone

```
Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    print(timeZoneName);
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  }
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (28341): Asia/Hong_Kong
```

```
tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTenAM() {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    print(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour,now.minute+1);
    print("called");
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    print(now.timeZoneName);
    print(now.timeZoneOffset);
    print(scheduledDate);
    return scheduledDate;
  }
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (22333): UTC
I/flutter (22333): 0:00:00.000000
I/flutter (22333): 2024-01-23 13:50:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use DateTime:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
print(dateTime.timeZoneName);
print(dateTime.timeZoneOffset);
```

source: [How to get current timezone region (tz database name) in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177378/how-to-get-current-timezone-region-tz-database-name-in-flutter)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the current problem is TZDateTime is using UTC+0 not other UTC.

Comment: @ZZZiioo What does tz.local print? In the docs they use the getLocation function again. And they use getLocation("...").timeZone for the offset

Comment: tz.local print output is UTC.

Comment: See my comment for possible solutions, otherwise I recommend reading the docs carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have to follow the doc and use the getLocation() function, but I find that it always initials to UTC0.

Comment: You need to change the `tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local)` to `tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.getLocation("Asia/Hong_Kong"))`